# Grails GORM query to match multiple associated objects

Tags: hibernate, grails, associations, grails-orm, h2

I'm having trouble figuring out a GORM query to match multiple associations on an object:

```
class Zoo {
    String name
    static hasMany = [animals:Animal]

    static namedQueries = {
        // SEARCH1 match any of a list of animals
        searchOr { searchAnimals ->
            or {
                searchAnimals.each { name ->
                    animals {
                        eq('name', name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // SEARCH2 match ALL of a list of animals
        searchAnd { searchAnimals ->
            and {
                searchAnimals.each { name ->
                    animals {
                        eq('name', name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Animal {
    String name
}
```

SEARCH1 will happily match a zoo with any of a list of animals, but how should SEARCH2 be written to get zoos which have ALL animals in the supplied list?

Comment: What happens when you move the and{} under searchAnimals.each{}

Comment: @jonaldomo I think the current `and` is implied anyway and so is unnecessary as it stands.  Moving it into `searchAnimals.each {}`, the implicit `and` would still be there, and the new `and` would be applied only to a single statement.  Can't hurt trying though - will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know GORM and I don't know a complete solution, but I think what the problem is with the current SEARCH2 query and what what could possibly help. The current searchOr is something like this:

```
WHERE ANIMAL.NAME = 'bear' 
   OR ANIMAL.NAME = 'bird' 
   OR ANIMAL.NAME = 'puma'
```

This will work well. The searchAnd is something like this:

```
WHERE ANIMAL.NAME = 'bear' 
  AND ANIMAL.NAME = 'bird' 
  AND ANIMAL.NAME = 'puma'
```

This can't give the correct result, because any single animal can't be a bear and a bird and a puma all at the same time.

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM ANIMAL A WHERE A.ZOO = Z.ID AND A.NAME = 'bear') 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT FROM ANIMAL A WHERE A.ZOO = Z.ID AND A.NAME = 'bird')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT FROM ANIMAL A WHERE A.ZOO = Z.ID AND A.NAME = 'puma')
```

But I don't know enough about GORM to be able to formulate a query in this way. From what I read there is an `exists` methods in [detached criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria). But maybe it's just not possible, except when using [Hibernate Query Language](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#hql).

Comment: thanks for helping to clarify the problem - should help me find if there's a solution :¬)